# ggplot: How to add a group average value as a line to a grouped bar chart in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, line, bar-chart

I would like to add the "All_Parties_average" value to my bar chart as a green line with a legend (see the second picture added by a link). Really appreciate the help!

Right now my graph looks like this:

[My graph at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XHGE.jpg)

This is kind of what I would like it to look like:

[End result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqidv.jpg)

Here is my data:

```
Gender <- as.factor(c("M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F"))
Political_Party <- as.factor(c("E200", "EKRE", "ERE", "Isamaa", "REF","Roh", "SDE", "Vabae", "Vasak", "KE","E200", "EKRE", "ERE", "Isamaa", "REF","Roh", "SDE", "Vabae", "Vasak", "KE"))
Media_coverage_average <- c(61,95,41,162,107,23,130,68,6,152,99,49,9,87,157,52,112,31,14,202)
All_Parties_average <- c(90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90)

my_data <- data.frame(Sugu, Political_Party, Media_coverage_average, All_Parties_average, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Also colors for the graph:

```
my_colors <- c(
  `Green` <- "#00a99d",
  `Purple` <- "#9424fb",
  `Grey` <- "#a6a6a6",
  `LightPurple` <- "#c991fd",
  `LightGrey` <- "#c9c9c9",
  `DarkGrey`<- "#636363",
  `ExtraDarkGrey`<- "#4c4c4c")
```

And my graph:

```
my_plot <- ggplot(my_data, aes(x = Political_Party, y = Media_coverage_average, fill = Gender))+
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")+
  geom_text(aes(label=Media_coverage_average), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25, size=6, family="Titillium Web", color= ExtraDarkGrey)+
  labs(x="Political Party", y="Average media coverage",
       caption = "Author")+
  theme_ipsum_tw(grid=FALSE, axis_text_size=18, axis_title_size = 16, caption_size = 15, base_size = 17, subtitle_size = 20)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Grey, Purple), labels = c("Mehed", "Naised"))

my_plot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionaly to @Senzeybek's answer, you can add a legend for the green line by passing its color into the `aes` of `geom_line` and setting the color by  using `scale_color_manual`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(my_data, aes(x = Political_Party, y = Media_coverage_average, fill = Gender))+
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")+
  geom_text(aes(label=Media_coverage_average), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25, size=6, family="Titillium Web", color= ExtraDarkGrey)+
  labs(x="Political Party", y="Average media coverage",
       caption = "Author")+
  #theme_ipsum_tw(grid=FALSE, axis_text_size=18, axis_title_size = 16, caption_size = 15, base_size = 17, subtitle_size = 20)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Grey, Purple), labels = c("Mehed", "Naised"))+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = All_Parties_average, color = "Average", group = 1), size = 2)+
  scale_color_manual(values = "green")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. Is it possible to make the line start and end at the edges? Right now it leaves two columns out that are on the edges? And also would like to remove the legend name colour? Thanks again!!

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly. Briefly, you can replace `geom_line` by `geom_hline` and `y` in `aes` by `yintercept`.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can add it with geom_line

```
my_plot <- ggplot(my_data, aes(x = Political_Party, y = Media_coverage_average, fill = Gender))+
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")+
  geom_text(aes(label=Media_coverage_average), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25, size=6, family="Titillium Web", color= ExtraDarkGrey)+
  labs(x="Political Party", y="Average media coverage",
       caption = "Author")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Grey, Purple), labels = c("Mehed", "Naised"))+
  theme_ipsum_tw(grid=FALSE, axis_text_size=18, axis_title_size = 16, caption_size = 15, base_size = 17, subtitle_size = 20)+
    geom_line(aes(y=All_Parties_average,group=1),size=1.5,color="green")
```

[image]